# My router IP address is different on different devices. Why?

Tags: router, ip, wireless-router

My whole Wi-Fi and internet home setup is not working at the moment. In trying to troubleshoot the whole thing, I ended up buying a new Wi-Fi router. When connecting to it from different devices, I sometime get different router IP addresses. Why is that?

For example:

**Device 1**

- IP address 92.18.210.46
- Subnet mask 255.255.240.0
- Router 92.18.208.1

**Device 2**

- IP address 192.168.1.110
- Subnet mask 255.255.0.0
- Router 192.168.1.1

The two devices are connected at the same time to the same router

Why do I have the same router with 2 different router IP addresses?

Comment: Sounds like Device 1 is bridged to the WAN. (Well, is it even configured with DHCP though?)

Comment: You're not doing the same check for both devices : For Device 1 the IP seems like the public IP (router IP), while for Device 2 it is in the local network.

Comment: Hah-ha. Router is a device to route packets between different networks(so it has different ips by defintion)..whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to plug the **WAN** port of your router in to the **LAN** port of your modem. In general, the WAN port is supposed to face "upstream"; toward the public Internet. LAN ports are supposed to face "downstream": toward your client devices.

It sounds like you plugged a LAN port from your router into the LAN port of your modem. This allows devices on your home LAN — both wired (Ethernet) or wireless (Wi-Fi) — to receive DHCP IP address leases from either your modem or your router. When a device receives more than one DHCP Offer, the device gets to pick for itself, using whatever heuristic it chooses, which Offer to accept. It sounds like some of your devices are choosing to accept offers from your modem, and others are choosing to accept offers from your router.

The solution is to make sure your router's **WAN** port is connected to your modem; this will keep your modem's DHCP server from making DHCP Offers to your LAN devices.